Erro comando UPDATE no SqLite não reconhece todos os filtros
O comando UPDATE do Sqlite não reconhece quando o filtro satisfaz todas as condições, por exemplo se a data do registro for igual a hoje ele atualiza todos os campos mencionados no SET, mas se for diferente de hoje ele reconhece todas as condições do filtro e não atualiza. E mesmo inserindo em uma Trigger o bug persiste. Segue o código para testes, obrigado!
SQLiteStudio - version v3.4.4
Tabelas do Projeto:
CREATE TABLE TBL_A (
    COD_LINHA     INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY,
    NM_BANCO      VARCHAR (10),
    DIAS_COMISSAO INTEGER,
    DT_FLUXO_INI  DATE,
    DT_FLUXO_FIM  DATE,
    NR_CONTRATO   VARCHAR (10),
    DT_COMISSAO   DATE
);

CREATE TABLE TBL_B (
    COD_LINHA        INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY,
    BOLETA_ATUAL     INTEGER,
    INSTRUMENTO      VARCHAR (10),
    EMISSOR          VARCHAR (10),
    APOLICE_AJUSTADA VARCHAR (10),
    VLR_COBRADO      DECIMAL (8, 2) 
);

Dados de testes:
insert into TBL_A (DT_FLUXO_INI, DT_FLUXO_FIM, NR_CONTRATO, DT_COMISSAO)
  values("01/01/2024", "31/05/2024", "123456",strftime('%d/%m/%Y', 'now')),
         ("01/02/2024", "31/06/2024", "123456","01/10/2024"),
         ("01/03/2024", "31/07/2024", "54321","01/09/2024"),
         ("01/04/2024", "31/08/2024", "54321",strftime('%d/%m/%Y', 'now'));
insert into TBL_B (BOLETA_ATUAL, INSTRUMENTO, NM_BANCO, APOLICE_AJUSTADA, VLR_COBRADO)
  values(11,"Fianças","ABC","12345",150.55),
          (12,"Fiança","ABC","12345",55.36),
          (13,"Fiança","ABC","12345",583.22),
          (14,"Fiança","REAL","54321",45.23),
          (15,"Fiança","REAL","54321",56.00),
          (16,"Fiança","REAL","54321",1587.33),
          (17,"Fiança","REAL","54321",999.25),
          (18,"Fiança","REAL","54321",52.01)

Update na Tabela A:
UPDATE TBL_A
   SET NM_BANCO = FI.EMISSOR,
       DIAS_COMISSAO = julianday(IC.dt_fluxo_fim - IC.dt_fluxo_ini)
              
  FROM TBL_A AS IC
       INNER JOIN
       TBL_B AS FI ON (FI.APOLICE_AJUSTADA = IC.NR_CONTRATO) 
 WHERE 1 = 1
       AND IC.DT_COMISSAO = strftime('%d/%m/%Y', 'now') 
       AND FI.INSTRUMENTO = 'Fiança'
       AND FI.BOLETA_ATUAL = ( SELECT MAX(BOLETA_ATUAL) 
                               FROM TBL_B
                              WHERE APOLICE_AJUSTADA = IC.NR_CONTRATO );


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
